# CSS Make text background height size increase animation

Tags: css, css-animations

How should I animate text (with writing-mode set to `vertical-rl`) background in CSS to increase its height when you hover over it? Something like this: https://youtu.be/A_ZS3aE_8Bw
Thanks!

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#text {
    --width: 2rem;
    font-size: var(--width);
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    position: relative;
}

#text::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: var(--width);
    height: 0;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#text:hover::before {
    height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
    <div id="text">hello world!</div>
```